# Gait/Walk analysis from sensor data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

i've assembled a carpet with 8 pressure sensors inside. You can see the sensors arrangement in the picture. The entire carpet is 80x80 cm. Each sensor ouptuts a digital signal (0 or 1) when is pressed. The microcontroller read all the sensors every 100 ms, and outputs a payload byte, where each bit contains the information of a single triangle. I'm storing all theese bytes in a 100 bytes long array. I need to calculate from this array the gait (the direction, the angle where the user is heading). The user is simply marching remaining on his spot, the feet are raised and lowered alternately. Do you know any algorithm wich i could be used to do this kind of analysis? Should i use machine learning / neural networks? Language doesn't matter, i just need to figure out the right way to analyse this byte array. Thanks!

[sensors inside the carpet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl6GN.png)